# How do I grow multiple generations of lima beans?

Tags: vegetables, beans

I am working on a school project and was wondering how fast can I grow lima beans indoor? What would be the minimum and maximum water, light and other nutrition I can expose them too? Do they need to grow aligned and how far apart should I plant them? 
Once the lima beans grow, can I get the immature beans inside the pod and regrow a second generation and so on? How would I do this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! While I applaud your scientific interest, please note that we can't do your homework for you. Wouldn't a school project warrant some experimentation? Like planting different pots and then watering / fertilizing / lighting differently? Suggestion: Do a quick websearch on some of your more basic issues like distance and generation length, narrow down your question here to a few points, state what you found so far and we'll gladly give you more pointers. As it stands, your question might be considered as too broad for here. Oh, and it's "Lima", not "Lime"...

Comment: Science is not about "asking the internet how to do it right" - it's about doing a bunch of things differently, while keeping other things the same, and reporting what actually happens. So take 5 and water and feed them the same while giving them different light levels.  take 5 and light and feed them the same while giving them different amounts of water. Take 5 and water and light them the same while giving them different amounts of food. keep feed, water and light the same with 5 sets planted at different spacings, etc. Remember, if some of them die, that's data, not failure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a homework question.

Comment: I get it J. Musser!!  This is an opportunity to educate a young person to the intricacies of growing plants.  Let's keep this open but let's be aware someone wants us to do their homework for them?  Need more information on what THEY are going to do...pictures.  If they don't jump through a few hoops we can't help them anyway.